# Get the currently selected option in a drop down as a string in Selenium + NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, node-modules

I need to get the currently selected option from the drop down as a String and print it out, but when I try the getText(), I get the complete list of items in the drop down, how can I get the currently selected item from a drop down?

Thanks. The HTML code is -

```
<select id="j_id0:j_id10:main_page_block:j_id45:0:j_id46:j_id47:3:j_id48" name="j_id0:j_id10:main_page_block:j_id45:0:j_id46:j_id47:3:j_id48"> 
<option value="">--None--</option>
<option value="Request">Request</option>
<option value="In Authoring" selected="selected">In Authoring</option>
<option value="In Signatures">In Signatures</option>
<option value="In Filing">In Filing</option>
<option value="In Effect">In Effect</option>
<option value="Expired">Expired</option>
<option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
<option value="Amended">Amended</option>
<option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
</select>
```

I have tried this but it only lists all the options present:

```
driver.findElement(By.id('j_id0:j_id10:main_page_block:j_id45:0:j_id46:j_id47:3:j_id48')).getText()
```

Comment: Kindly Add relevant HTML code

Comment: @IshitaShah Added the HTML

Comment: And your trial code also,

Comment: @IshitaShah I have added what I tried.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

If  you have single drop down on Web page,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@selected='selected']")).getText();
```

If you have multiple drop down on Web page,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='j_id0:j_id10:main_page_block:j_id45:0:j_id46:j_id47:3:j_id48']//option[@selected='selected']")).getText();
```